# Hash whose values are array size

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I need a method that will take a hash and return a hash whose keys are from the old hash and values are the size of the arrays in the old hash. I.e.,

```
{ 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }
# return
{ 1 => 3, 2 => 3, 7 => 2 }
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way:

```
h = { 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }

h.merge(h) { |*_,a| a.size }
  #=> { 1 => 3, 2 => 3, 7 => 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but @cbuilard answer is more understandable for me

Comment: very nice answer. If I was the OP then I must select this as answered. Bcz it's different and simple

Comment: likewise `*_` can become `_`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map` to build a new array of `[key, value]` pairs and then convert it back to a hash using `to_h`:

```
input = { 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }
input.map { |key, value| [key, value.length] }.to_h

# => {1=>3, 2=>3, 7=>2}
```

Comment: Your answer is the shortest in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: I like this because it is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straightforward: you can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to process all the items one by one and compose the result.

```
input = { 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }
input.inject({}) do |result, (key, value)|
  result.merge(key => value.size)
end

# => {1=>3, 2=>3, 7=>2}
```

Even without inject, just use `.each` to loop all the items and construct the result using a temporary support `Hash`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, a solution using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
input = { 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }

input.each_with_object({}) { |(k, vs), h| h[k] = vs.size }
#=> {1=>3, 2=>3, 7=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to insert the expected keys and values into the new Hash:

```
h = { 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }
h2 = {}
h.each {|k, v| h2[k] = v.length}
h2
# => {1=>3, 2=>3, 7=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h.keys.zip(h.values.map &:size).to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this,

```
h = { 1 => [1,1,1], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => [9,12] }
Hash[h.map {|key, value| [key, value.length]}]
#  => {1=>3, 2=>3, 7=>2}
```